# combine multiple dataframes based on sequence of names

Tags: r, list, dataframe, merge, rbind

Say I have 30 dataframes all named with a date from `01/01/2000` to `30/01/2000` in the format of `ddmmyy` (code below) :

```
Season <- seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"),as.Date("2000-01-30"),1)
Season <- format(Season,"%d%m%y")

for (s in Season) {

  df <- data.frame(X=1:10, Y=1:10)

  aa <- paste(s,"tests",s ,sep = "_")

  assign(aa,df)

}
```

Each name, you cans see, has the word `tests` added to it.I want to combine (`rbind`?) the `data.frame`s based on the date. In this case, combine `data.frame`s that **contain** the dates from `01-01-00` to `10-01-00`.

I have the below code to combine all dataframes but what if I only want to select the ones shown above?

```
All_dfs <- do.call(rbind, eapply(.GlobalEnv,function(x) if(is.data.frame(x)) x))
```

Is it better to create a list first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `mget` to get the values of 'Season' in a `list` and then `rbind` the `list` of `data.frame`s.  As there is a suffix "*tests*" followed by "Season" concatenated to the "Season", we can use `paste` to get the string, then use `mget`.

```
res <- do.call(rbind, mget( paste0(Season[1:10], "_tests_", Season[1:10])))
dim(res)
#[1] 100   2
```

Comment: akrun thank you! I shot myself in the foot by trying to make it a simpler question but have now made the edits. Could you have a look please? I want to select the `data.frame`s that contain `Season[1:10]`

Comment: @Bonono UPdated the post

Comment: @ akrun, brilliant thank you. Just to complicate it further, what if the suffix was different for every dataframe - have edited the question